# Error message while inspecting elements using appium inspector on android

Tags: appium-android

When ever I am staring my Appium inspector i get below error

**An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'adb.exe -P 5037 -s b99a78b6 shell pm clear c' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'Error: java.lang.SecurityException: PID 20535 does not have permission android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA to clear data of package com.testApp.sample'; Code: '1'**

Below are my JSON Representation

```
 {
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "8.1.0",
  "deviceName": "b99a78b6",
  "Android": "C:\\Users\\testUser\\test.apk",
  "appPackage": "com.testApp.sample",
  "appActivity": "com.testApp.sample.SplashActivity"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MI restricts executing commands on device through USB. To enable this, you have to enable USB debugging(security settings), this can be found in the developer options.

Comment: Search for "Disable Permission Monitoring" and Enable it. This will help resolving the Issue with Android 8 and above

Comment: Yes this worked after enabling "Disable permission monitor". Also there is another option i found from other blogs by adding "noReset": "true" in the json rep